# GLCM Texture analysis in Sentinel-1 SNAP toolbox outputs texture with min and max pixel values not between 0 and 1

Tags: image-processing, feature-extraction, glcm

I have implemented GLCM Texture analysis on the Sentinel-1 SAR imagery. The imagery is high resolution. The parameters for the GLCM texture analysis are:

**Window size: 5x5**

**Quantizer: Probablistic Quantizer**

**Quantization: 64 bit**

**Angle: 0 degree**

**Displacement: 1**

The output is 10 different texture images. However the range of pixel values is not between 0 and 1. The range for every texture is between different min and max values. I believe this should be between 0 and 1 as it is a probabilistic analysis with GLCM that is being calculated for every pixel.

Am I missing a step?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are getting 10 different images because for each image pixel you are performing the following operations:

- Define a neighbourhood of 5×5 centered at the considered pixel.
- Compute the GLCM corresponding to `displacement=1` and `angle=0` of that neighbourhood.
- Extract 10 features from the local GLCM.

This results in a stack of 10 images, one image for each feature extracted from the local GLCMs.

The problem is that [Haralick features](http://murphylab.web.cmu.edu/publications/boland/boland_node26.html) are not normalized to 1. Consider for example the standard definition of entropy:

[image: Entropy]

If you wish to obtain entropy value in the range `[0, 1]` you should divide the equation above by the maximum entropy (measured in bits), like this:

[image: Normalized entropy]

where [image: N_g] is the number of different grey levels.

[This paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S016786551400124X?via%3Dihub) explains how to normalize *contrast*, *correlation*, *energy*, *entropy* and *homogeneity* features extracted from GLCM so that they have range [0, 1].

Comment: So, this means even though it is a probabilistic analysis, the min and max value will not be between 0 and 1. In order to do so, I will have to divide each pixel value (probability) by the max pixel value present in the image. Am I right?

Comment: The GLCM is normalized so that the sum of their elements is 1. However, not all the Haralick features are normalized to the range 0-1. Concretely, the entropy of the GLCM can be greater than 1 (as shown in my answer). [This paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S016786551400124X?via%3Dihub) explains how to normalize 5 Haralick features to have range [0, 1].